# How to create a parent/child hierarchy in Swift

Tags: swift

Newbie programmer here! So the app I’m building has a class of repair items and a repair item bank containing the information. A repair item can have children repair items, but not all do. So I've looked into using a tree data structure within a class in order to do this.

But it seems like have mostly empty nodes is inefficient. I'd like to present further repair items if a parent repair item is selected by the user. Is there a better way of handling this?

```
class PropertyItem {
    let itemDepartment : String
    let repairPrice : Float
    let repairItem : String
    let itemCategory : String
    let multiplyByArea : Bool
    var repairItemChildren = [String?]()

    init(itemDepartment : String, itemCategory : String, repairPrice : Float, repairItem : String, multiplyByArea : Bool, repairItemChildren : [String?]) {
        self.itemDepartment = itemDepartment        
        self.itemCategory = itemCategory                 
        self.repairPrice = repairPrice
        self.repairItem = repairItem
        self.multiplyByArea = multiplyByArea
        self.repairItemChildren = repairItemChildren
    }
}

class PropertyItemBank {
    var departmentArray = [PropertyItem]()

    init() {
        departmentArray.append(PropertyItem(itemDepartment: "Exterior", itemCategory: "Foundation", repairPrice: 2.00, repairItem: "Siding", multiplyByArea: true, repairItemChildren: [nil]))
        departmentArray.append(PropertyItem(itemDepartment: "Exterior", itemCategory: "Foundation", repairPrice: 2.00, repairItem: "Siding", multiplyByArea: true, repairItemChildren: ["Bricks", "Wood"]))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"So the app I’m building has a class of repair items and a repair item bank containing the information. A repair item can have children repair items, but not all do." Not sure if i understand this enough in order to to tell which one is the superclass.

You should subclass. Set your repairItem as your superclass and then for the items with extra properties you subclass them

```
 class repairItemsWithExtraProperties: repairItems{ }
```

check the documentation for detailed explanation: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Inheritance.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question, but is this what you are looking for?  Having your children array as optional lets you not consume space with empty arrays and only instantiate them if children objects need to be added.

```
class PropertyItem {

    let itemDepartment : String
    let repairPrice : Float
    let repairItem : RepairItem
    let itemCategory : String
    let multiplyByArea : Bool

}

class RepairItem {

    var title : String?
    var children : [RepairItem]?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to say THANK YOU to all that replied. I apologize for phrasing my question more clearly. Essentially, what I needed what a way to relate two of the same type of objects. In other words, I wanted to show linked objects (of same type) if a parent object was selected by the user. I got it to work by storing an array of children item objects. I'm posting my code in case anyone in the future runs into a similar circumstance.

```
class PropertyItem {

let itemDepartment : String
let repairPrice : Float
let repairItem : String
let itemCategory : String
let multiplyByArea : Bool
var repairItemChildren : Array = [PropertyItem?]()

init(itemDepartment : String, itemCategory : String, repairPrice : Float, repairItem : String, multiplyByArea : Bool, repairItemChildren : [PropertyItem?]) {

    self.itemDepartment = itemDepartment
    self.itemCategory = itemCategory
    self.repairPrice = repairPrice
    self.repairItem = repairItem
    self.multiplyByArea = multiplyByArea
    self.repairItemChildren = repairItemChildren

    }

}



class PropertyItemBank {

var departmentArray = [PropertyItem]()

init() {

    departmentArray.append(PropertyItem(itemDepartment: "Exterior", itemCategory: "Foundation", repairPrice: 2.00, repairItem: "Siding", multiplyByArea: true, repairItemChildren: [nil]))

    departmentArray.append(PropertyItem(itemDepartment: "Exterior", itemCategory: "Foundation", repairPrice: 2.00, repairItem: "Siding", multiplyByArea: true, repairItemChildren: [PropertyItem(itemDepartment: "Exterior", itemCategory: "Foundation", repairPrice: 2.00, repairItem: "Siding Child", multiplyByArea: true, repairItemChildren: [nil])]))

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

"A repair item can have children repair items, but not all do."
If you are referring to:

```
var repairItemChildren: [String] = [String]()
```

don't store it as an optional. 
if the array is empty, you don't have repair item children, else you do

```
init(itemDepartment : String, itemCategory : String, repairPrice : Float, repairItem : String, multiplyByArea : Bool, repairItemChildren : [String]?) {

    self.itemDepartment = itemDepartment        
    self.itemCategory = itemCategory                 
    self.repairPrice = repairPrice
    self.repairItem = repairItem
    self.multiplyByArea = multiplyByArea
    if let children = repairItemChildren {
        self.repairItemChildren = children
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I understand how I’d check if there are children, but how would I actually retrieve those children repair items? Should I store repair item objects in the array?

Comment: Yes, instead of storing String type, store RepairItem (or whatever your object is)

Comment: "*if the array is empty, you have repair item children, else you don't*" - that's backwards.